# Why I obtain this exception when I try to retrieve a .properties file in this simple Java batch program?

Tags: java, properties-file, resourcebundle

I am working on a Java batch and I am finding the following problem.

Into my code I have something like this:

```
public class StartScaricoRol {

    private static final String RESOURCE_FILE_PATH = "java.com.fideuram.batch.rol.resource.settings";

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        myResources = ResourceBundle.getBundle( RESOURCE_FILE_PATH );

        ..............................................................
        ..............................................................
        ..............................................................
}
```

Where the **java.com.fideuram.batch.rol.resource.settings** should represent the **settings.properties** file inside the **java.com.fideuram.batch.rol.resource** package of my project, infact I have this project structure:

[image]

The problem is that when this line is executed:

```
myResources = ResourceBundle.getBundle( RESOURCE_FILE_PATH );
```

the following exception is thrown:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name java.com.XXX.batch.rol.resource.settings, locale it_IT
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1427)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1250)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:705)
    at com.XXX.batch.rol.StartScaricoRol.main(StartScaricoRol.java:44)
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Why'd you scrape out the class name from the image, but not the stack trace or code?

Comment: Editing in the question still leaves it in the history so if you are concerned about that, delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Place the resource in the directory src/main/resources/my.package.name so that Maven finds and copies it to the correct location